# How do I reduce strain gage drift?

Tags: strain-gage, drift, labview

my name is Joe Vaccarella. I am a research assistant at the University of Rochester.

I’m currently conducting a project where I have 4 strain gages, mounted on a polycarbonate tube. (one gage on each inner face) On top of this tube is a 6x6” Polycarb plate. My current experimentation involves placing various masses on top of this plate, and then measuring the change in strain for each gage.

Hardware:

- (4) Micro-Measurement Pre-Wired Strain Gages (ID:
  C4A-06-235SL-120/39P)
- NI 9235 C Series Bridge Input Module
- NI CompactDAQ-9174 Chassis

I am able to read data from the gages, and they appear to be acting linearly for the most part. The issue I’m currently running into is that the gage measurements like to drift, seemingly in arbitrary directions.
I’ve been searching internet forums for some time now, trying to find a way to reduce the drift that we’ve been encountering.

- Initially we had an idea to lower the excitation voltage, in an
  attempt to reduce the potential noise present in the system. After
  some searching, I discovered that our current input module (the 9235)
  only supplies an excitation voltage of 2 volts, and it seems like we
  can’t modify it.
- I may be wrong about this though as I'm inexperienced in this hardware and I would appreciate any and all feedback that can be given.

I’ve also heard that because we mounted to plastic instead of metal, we should expect increased drift, and poorer zero return.

For context, the gages will drift a few 10’s of microstrain at random points in time. This ‘shifting’ is gradual most of the time, occurring over the period of 10 seconds or so. This occurs when the system is both loaded and unloaded.
Based on initial testing, we expect to encounter readings less than a 100 microstrain when we go to conduct the actual experiment, which we believe is well within the optimal working range of our current strain gages.

I would appreciate any feedback on how to reduce this drift, either through a change in something I’m doing in LabView, or a physical change to the system.
I will attach a few images for reference.

- For context, I’ve only been using the built-in strain calibration
  wizard for LabView, so I don't really have much LabView code to
  share, but I'll attach my current file anyways.

Thanks for reading this!
[image]
[image]

Comment: The strain gage [datasheet is here](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cdn.vpg-web.com/rs/filestore/1/2/1/4/1_0b06e12a9da1ba0/12141_bdd7081aabdcb16.pdf)

Comment: A first step in my mind would be to change the circumstances for your strain gauges to a still simpler one with fewer experimental vagaries in the physics going on and then carefully test the strain gauges, themselves, along with better (if you can find it) and more reliable equipment that has itself been well-qualified and tested, independently. See if this is a matter of the strain gauge itself. Do you have other equipment you can borrow for reading the strain gauges?

Comment: Do you have the gauges wired together in a bridge, or are you measuring them individually? If you're measuring them individually, do all 4 drift in the same direction at the same time?

Comment: I'm at UR, by the way

Comment: step 0: replace strain gage with thermally stable precision resistor bridge, see what you get. Divide and conquer. Is it the gage or the rest of the setup....

Comment: If you suspect the gage, how was the surface prepared and bonded?  (fine sandpaper, high purity isoprop clean and cyanoacrylate. or epoxy?)  the process affects  creap.

Answer (score 2):

The FIRST thing to do is to look at the signal with a very fine time scale to make sure the "drift" you're experiencing isn't big noise or an oscillation that's aliased in your display or your sampling scheme.  This has bit me in the butt more than once when working with strain gages (more often than I like to admit!).

If it does turn out to be noise or oscillation, you can either find and kill the source (start by twisting any long wires together), or filter them out, if the filter doesn't interfere with your frequencies of interest.

Servoing your Vcc's at the bridge really can help, if Bridge Voltage drift is your issue.

[image]

The above image is from [AD's Transducer Interfacing Handbook](https://www.analog.com/en/education/education-library/transducer-interfacing-handbook.html), figure 2-5, on bridge excitation schemes.

I also find that sometimes breezes impact the temp (you need to keep current in your bridge low.  Cover them up to shield them if possible.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Very good point regarding doing a test at a larger time scale, we're definitely going to look at that next. If we find any long-term oscillation, we'll try out your tips. On another note, I'm a bit confused as to what you mean by 'servoing' in this context, also what are the VCC's are in this case? We'll also keep a look out for any breezes/drafts within our testing room.

Comment: The bridge output will vary with the bridge excitation voltage, and long wires and noise can have an impact.  Since the current in the sense lead is minimal, there is no IR drop, so the feedback system has the effect of holding the bridge voltage right where you want it.  It is "servoed"

Answer (score 1):

If your intent was to make a bar load cell then the gauges have to be mounted in pairs of different directions:

[image]

Note that strain gauges are made from different materials so that can match the temperature coefficient of a body alloy material - of course the body is always made of metal alloy.

A such cell (bar cell) is not suited to be used as a platform weighing scale, because it would bend if it is rigidly coupled to the platform. You have to use 4 of them in each corner - this is how a truck weighing works.

For a platform scale, a beam cell is appropriate.

[image]

The platform is mounted on top by means of levers and ball joints, scissor like mechanism that transfers the force only in up/down direction. Further, the platform or the cell has to have a lock pin that prevents excess movement.

In most cases the cell itself is never rigidly coupled to the load structure.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response. Upon further reflection, I do now realize how our current setup functionally acts as a load cell. Earlier in the project, we debated using a load cell at each corner but we weren't sure if we would be able to create a mathematical model which would allow us to calculate the position of the resultant force using data from the cells.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like thermal noise or 1/f noise, if you have the electronics set correct.

First, you may try it in a controlled temperature environment, just to see if the noise is coming from the temperature drift.

Very slow drift around resistors and passive devices in the circuitry can cause noise, that the related parameters can be found from the device manufacturer's doc.

For, temperature stability, I may propose to use "wheatstone bridge" strain gauge. That can cancel out temperature drift due to the "ratiometric measurement" nature.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Good point as well, moving forward we are going to try to test in temperature-stabilized environments, and see the effect that has on our measurements.